# Using multiprocessing to create two arrays in python simultaneously

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing

I've written a python script that uses numpy to create two arrays from different sources of data and compares them to each other. Building the arrays is quite a slow process so I wanted to find a way of building them at the same time to speed the script up. I tried to do this using the multiprocessing module like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
       p1 = Process(target=network_matrix_main_function(input_network))
       p1.start()
       p2 = Process(target=tree_matrix_main_function(input_tree))
       p2.start()
       print p1
       print p2
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bj5/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/bj5/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 113, in run
    if self._target:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
<Process(Process-1, stopped[1])>
<Process(Process-2, started)>
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bj5/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/bj5/homebrew/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 113, in run
    if self._target:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It sounds to me like python is struggling to handle the fact that the output from both the parallel processes is an array and not a single value. I've tried googling a.any() and a.all() (which it suggests to use in the final line of the error message) for use with multiprocessing and arrays but haven't been able to find anything that tells me how to use them.

Can anyone explain to me why my script doesn't work and what I need to do to run the two functions: network_matrix_main_function, and tree_matrix_main_function in parallel?

Comment: From the docs, it looks like `target` should be a `function`.  But is `network_matrix_main_function(input_network)` a `function` or a value of some type?  It looks like a function call, which evaluates immediately to a value, not a `function`.

Comment: It's a function call, if you just right the name of the function how do you give the argument to the function?

Answer (score 0):

that is pretty easy to fix. You see, with multiprocessing you have to seperate the function and the arguments:

```
p1 = Process(target=[some function], args=[(some arguments,other args)])
```

Also, you shouldn't print Processes, but define in their function that they should print out something,

And lastly, you should join the Processes back together with the .join() function.